# Why do I get the illegal start of type with this program? I just started it but don't see where I went wrong

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

```
//NEX GUI
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class NEX { extends JFrame

    private static final int WIDTH =500;
    private static final int HEIGHT =175;

    public NEX()
    {
      setTitle("New Customer"); //sets the title of the frame
      setSize(Width,Height);
    }        


    /**
      * @param args the command line arguments
      */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame aNEX =new NEX();
      aNEX.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      aNEX.setVisible(true); //display the frame
      // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: `setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);`

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
public class NEX {extends JFrame
```

should be

```
public class NEX extends JFrame {
```

since you're working in Java.

Also, as pointed out by Joop Eggen, the code `setSize(Width,Height);` should be `setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);` since you used all caps when you declared them.